# React: Importing a function and passing states to it not working

Tags: reactjs

**Hi new to react,i can't call the function Adder from an other file, I'm receiving an error Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component...i need to pass states to it and call it how can i do it?**

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react'
    import {SnacksContext, Snacks} from './Snacks'
    import {Adder} from './adderMethod'
const AddSnack=()=>{
const [snack,setSnacks]=useContext(SnacksContext)

const [{product,price,picture},setValues]=Handler({
    product:"",
    price:"",
    picture:""
})
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>add item:</h1>
            <input name="product" value={product} onChange={setValues} placeholder="name"></input>
            <input name="price"  type="number" value={price}  onChange={setValues} placeholder="price"></input>
            <input name="picture" value={picture}  onChange={setValues} placeholder="image(add images/)"></input>
            <button onClick={()=>Adder(product,price,picture)}>add item</button> /*<--this part is wrong*/

        </div>
    )
}
export default AddSnack
```

**Im trying to call the function below from another file**

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react'
    import {SnacksContext, Snacks} from './Snacks'
    export const Adder=(x,y,z)=>{
        const [snacks,setSnacks]=useContext(SnacksContext)
        setSnacks([...snacks,{product:x,price:y,picture:z}])
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at `Adder`, you call the hook `useContext`. since you call `Adder` at button on click, you are calling `useContext` hook outside of component's body. I suggest you tweak your `Adder` to return the state handler and snacks as the following:

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react'
import {SnacksContext, Snacks} from './Snacks'
export const Adder = () => {
  const [snacks,setSnacks] = useContext(SnacksContext)
  const updateSnacks = (x , y, z) => setSnacks([...snacks,{product:x,price:y,picture:z}])
  return [snacks, updateSnacks]
}
```

now at `AddSnack` component you call your hook at its body  retrieving snacks and updateSnacks:

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react'
import { Adder } from './adderMethod'

const AddSnack = () => {
const [snacks, updateSnacks]= Adder()
```

at button now you can call your updateSnacks safety:

```
<button onClick={() => updateSnacks(product,price,picture)}>add item</button>
```

Comment: Thank u very much sir! I'm wrestling this problem for quite a while